# Is a VPN enough to hide my trafic from my schools IT department?

Tags: wifi, vpn, tor

At my school we log on WiFi with a personal login. If I wanted to hide the traffic from my computer from the network administrators would it be enough for me to use a VPN service like for example PrivateInternetAccess or should I use Tor?

Comment: Short Answer, Yes. (Unless it's a split tunnel vpn, but anything provided by a security vpn service would not be split tunnel.)

Comment: TTT, yes an in PrivateInternetAccess is enough, or Tor? ;)

Comment: Yes, as in a correctly configured full tunnel vpn is sufficient. I don't know the specifics of those particular services.

Comment: [Related question and answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/72679/differences-between-using-tor-browser-and-vpn/72729#72729)