# How to prevent my ISP from seeing what sites I visit without a VPN

Tags: windows, web-browser, vpn, internet, isp

I use opera browser, and while the built-in VPN has been working relatively well it's been preventing me from joining discord voice calls and using omegle. Is there a way to hide my activity from my ISP without encountering those problems?

Comment: Have you considered Tor?

Comment: Potentialduplicate: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/72679/differences-between-using-tor-browser-and-vpn

Comment: The short answer is it depends on how the ISP is doing traffic analysis (if at all).  If they're doing it via deep packet inspection, and looking at the SSL certificates going between you and the internet, you'd need some form of VPN.  If they're doing it via simply analyzing DNS traffic (which honestly is FAR easier and less computational) then simply enabling DNS over HTTPS will stop them.  https://developers.cloudflare.com/1.1.1.1/dns-over-https/web-browser  This of course means you trust whomever is providing you DNS over https.